# NotFoundError: iris_training.csv

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using Colab to repeat the exercise provided here: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/yufengg/a6dff912ab48f7a273f5704ad9ab1311
I changed the Tensorflow to version 1.3.0, However, I got the error as shown like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtdsG.png)
Any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the data too.

Try adding this

```
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/h2oai/h2o-2/master/smalldata/iris/iris_train.csv
```